# Python Fileinput openhook=fileinput.hook_compressed syntax use

Tags: python, gzip, glob, file-io

I'm trying to open a number of files using glob and feed them through a series of functions. Some of my files are gziped some are bz2 and some are plain text. I used fileinput typically but can't figure out the syntax to have it take in compressed files. Based on this [Python Fileinput Doc](http://docs.python.org/library/fileinput.html) it should be something like:

```
openhook=fileinput.hook_compressed
```

My code looks like:

```
import fileinput
import glob

filestobeanalyzed = glob.glob('./files/*')

for fileName in filestobeanalyzed:
    inputfilename = fileName
    for line in fileinput.input([inputfilename, openhook=fileinput.hook_compressed]):
        #do stuff
```

I get an invalid syntax on the fileinput line at the = sign.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want

```
for line in fileinput.input(inputfilename, openhook=fileinput.hook_compressed):
    #do stuff
```

(I removed the square brackets).  You were trying to do an assignment in a list constructor.  e.g.

```
my_list=["foo",bar="baz"]  #this doesn't work (SyntaxError)
```

You probably got the idea from the python documentation which uses `[` and `]` to indicate optional arguments to functions.

This is just an aside -- often there is more information in the traceback which can help pin down the problem than just the type of error and the line number.  (read:  When you have a traceback, it's generally appreciated if you paste the whole thing so we can see it)

Comment: actually that was the entire traceback, just "syntax error on =" and an arrow pointing to the location. Thanks though and yes I got the idea from the python documentation. Your solution worked great, thanks again.